# Does `xdotool key --delay` pause for specified delay between typing every two consecutive keys?

Tags: xdotool

manpage of xdotool says

> -- delay milliseconds Delay between keystrokes. Default is 12ms.

I thought that `key string` will type each character in the string once, and `--delay` is for pause between typing two consecutive characters. So why do the following first two commands not show typing anything, while the third types twice, and the last types many times? Thanks.

```
$ xdotool key 9
$ xdotool key --delay 2 9
$ xdotool key --delay 1000 9
99$ xdotool key --delay 10000 9
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999^C
```

I am using Lubuntu 18.04 and

```
$ xdotool -v
xdotool version 3.20160805.1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the first or second on 14.04 or 18.04, and I can't reproduce the third on 18.04. In any case, it seems like a bug.

Comment: BTW it's easier to test `xdotool` commands in terminal if you add a short delay first, like `sleep 0.1 && xdotool key 9`

Comment: Thanks. I added my version. What does `--delay` mean ideally?

Comment: Ideally it's the delay between consecutive keystrokes, just like you said.

Comment: `key --delay <n> 9` should type the key 9 once, whatever value   `n` has, and thus only a single digit is displayed, correct?

Comment: That's correct. BTW I just noticed `xdotool type` is also affected. E.g. trying `sleep 0.1 && xdotool type --delay 2000 hello` types `hheelllloo`

Comment: Why "it's easier to test xdotool commands in terminal if you add a short delay first"?

Comment: Indeed with longer delays, it is as if the key autorepeat is kicking into action. If longer delays are needed, use sleep.

Comment: @Tim A short delay prevents any of your keystrokes from conflicting with the xdotool keystrokes, but there's not much chance of conflicts in this case.

Comment: @wjandrea  By "conflict", do you mean the same as the case when I type a sequence of characters from keyboard, the computer may accept the characters in a different order? (This happens when my RAM or CPU is being heavily used.)

Comment: @Tim By "conflict" I mean for example if you hold down Shift and run `xdotool key m` at the same time, you will get a capital M instead of a small m.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks. That is different from the case (also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099816/why-are-the-characters-that-i-typed-missing-or-out-of-order). I also remember the out or order problem sometimes happens when I use xdotool.

Answer (score 6):

The manual indeed says

> Delay between keystrokes. Default is 12ms.

This leads to expect that between each (simulated) press and release of a key, there will be a delay by the set value. The option, however, behaves rather as if the key is pressed during the period indicated by the delay, with no such delay in between different key presses. When the delay is long enough, autorepeat kicks in and the character is repeated.

To obtain the desired behavior where there is a pause between keypresses, one should rather use the `sleep` command:

```
xdotool sleep 1 key 9
```

<kbd>9</kbd> will be pressed after one second. Two consecutive keypresses one second apart can be issued by

```
xdotool sleep 1 key 9 sleep 1 key 2
```

Alternatively, when working with bash scripts, a delay can be introduced using the bash `sleep` command between invocations of `xdotool`.

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
xdotool key 9
sleep 1
xdotool key 2
```